# Serialize JSON String to AVRO Apache Beam KafkaIO

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a JSON String that needs to be serialized to AVRO format so that I can publish that to a Kafka topic that has an Avro schema with schema validation on it. Below is what I have tried so far but it gives a validation error.

```
@Override     
public PDone expand(PCollection<Product> input) {
    return input.apply("Write to Kafka Topic", KafkaIO.<Void, String>write().
                withBootstrapServers(kafkaUrl)
                .withTopic(kafkaTopic)
//                .withKeySerializer(StringSerializer.class)
                .withValueSerializer(StringSerializer.class)
```

The error I am getting is

```
send failed : 'This record has failed the validation on broker and hence be rejected.'
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: @chamikara This is the error. send failed : 'This record has failed the validation on broker and hence be rejected.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is serializing strings. UTF-8 Strings are not binary Avro.

You need to apply a [`ParDo`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo), or [`MapElements`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/mapelements/) to the `input` from Strings/JSON into a Avro record type such as `GenericRecord`, or a generated `SpecificRecord` class.

For example,

```
// Product is defined by an AVSC file and generated from avro-maven-plugin
pipeline
.apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<JSONProduct, Product>() {
  @Override
  public Product apply(JSONProduct input) {
    try {
      return AvroConverterFactory.convertProduct(input);  // TODO: Implement this yourself
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Converter Error", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}))
.apply(Filter.by(Objects::nonNull)) // assuming you don't want nulls downstream
```

Then you should be able to use something like this

Note: It seems to compile, but does throw a runtime error saying the class cannot be cast... Seems like a bug.

```
  @Override
  public POutput expand(PCollection<Product> input) {
    //noinspection unchecked
    return input.apply("Write to Kafka", KafkaIO.<Void, Product>write()
        .withBootstrapServers("localhost:29092")
        .withTopic("foobar")
        .withValueSerializer((Class<? extends Serializer<Product>>) KafkaAvroSerializer.class)
        .withProducerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of(
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081"
        )).values());
  }
```

The (unfortunate) workaround is to define your own wrapper class

```
  public static class ProductSerializer implements Serializer<Product> {

    private final KafkaAvroSerializer inner;

    public ProductSerializer() {
      inner = new KafkaAvroSerializer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
      inner.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Product product) {
      return inner.serialize(topic, product);
    }

  }
```

Then this will work

```
  @Override
  public POutput expand(PCollection<Product> input) {
    return input.apply("Write to Kafka", KafkaIO.<Void, Product>write()
        .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
        .withTopic("foobar")
        .withValueSerializer(ProductSerializer.class)
        .withProducerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of(
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081"
        )).values());
  }
```

I used a very simple Avro schema, but

```
$ kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic foobar --from-beginning
{"name":"Hello"}
{"name":"World"}
```

Comment: After changing to a GenericRecord, I get a compile error saying, Required type:
Class
<? extends Serializer<GenericRecord>> Provided:
Class
<KafkaAvroSerializer>

Comment: The tests use a reader with `GenericRecord`, though... https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIOTest.java#L447

Comment: Since this is how the signature looks like, I cant make it Object `@Override
    public PDone expand(PCollection<Product> input) {`

Comment: Why not? `PDone` doesn't have a type that depends on what the pipeline does

Comment: So in that case I would have to output an Object type from the previous DoFn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241225/discussion-between-turingman-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: @turingMan I have updated the post with a solution that worked for me

Comment: This worked! Thanks a ton!

Comment: When we publish messages like this, can we use the AvroDeserializer to consume messages as well?

Comment: I was able to get it working locally, yes.. I had to make a class that `implements Deserializer<Product>`, though, and use that similar to how I did here for the serializer